# lzma_stream_encoder_mt_memusage missing from dpkg-deb

Tags: dpkg, lzma

Recently, after an interrupted `dist-upgrade`, I've been experiencing some issues with `dpkg-deb`.

Most frequently, I get one specific issue:

> `dpkg-deb: relocation error: dpkg-deb: symbol lzma_stream_encoder_mt_memusage, version XZ_5.2 not defined in file liblzma.so.5 with link time reference`

The message is very clear, but it's not clear to me how this should be fixed.

- I've tried reinstalling `liblzma5` from the default 17.10 PPAs, with no dice.
- I've also tried to `apt install --reinstall dpkg`, also to no effect.
- I've tried installing `liblzma5` from source and updating my `$LDPATH` to reflect the new build's path, but I'm not sure which flags to use to export the missing symbol; a plain `./configure && make && make install` doesn't seem to.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I'm having the same error after a "do-release upgrade" from xenial -> bionic

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by copying the file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.2.2
from a machine already upgraded to bionic.